# Meteor Up deployment, can't use meteor mongo --url

Tags: mongodb, ssh, meteor, digital-ocean, meteor-up

I've recently deployed my Meteor app to a Digital Ocean droplet running Ubuntu 14.04 x32. I used [Meteor Up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) with this `mup.json` file:

```js
{
  // Server authentication info
  "servers": [
    {
      "host": "mycorrecthostname",
      "username": "root",
      "password": "mycorrectpassword"
    }
  ],

  // Install MongoDB in the server, does not destroy local MongoDB on future setup
  "setupMongo": true,

  // WARNING: Node.js is required! Only skip if you already have Node.js installed on server.
  "setupNode": true,

  // WARNING: If nodeVersion omitted will setup 0.10.25 by default. Do not use v, only version number.
  "nodeVersion": "0.10.28",

  // Install PhantomJS in the server
  "setupPhantom": true,

  // Application name (No spaces)
  "appName": "meteor",

  // Location of app (local directory)
  "app": "/my/correct/path/to/app",

  // Configure environment
  "env": {
    "ROOT_URL": "http://mycorrecturl.com"
  },

  // Meteor Up checks if the app comes online just after the deployment
  // before mup checks that, it will wait for no. of seconds configured below
  "deployCheckWaitTime": 15
}
```

Everything works great. I have tested the website, and everything works just the way it should. I've also set up my `ssh` keys with the server, and can `ssh` to it without a password.

Now though, I need to access my server database remotely. I have some local data in a python `shelf` file that I need to seed my database with. I understand how to connect to a remote database with `pymongo`, but I'm trying to get a connection URI with `meteor mongo --url http://mycorrecturl.com/` and it just returns this error:

```
Couldn't open a mongo connection: Site does not exist
```

**What??** What is going wrong here? I would expect it to ask for authentication, but just not existing? Officially confused.

Your help is appreciated in advance!

### Update

I've been hunting around in my server directories, trying to successfully run `meteor mongo` there, but despite the fact that I've installed meteor with `curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh`, it simply always says that I'm not in a meteor project directory. Even the hidden `.meteor` directory apparently wasn't a project directory.

### Update

I've looked more closely at the Meteor Up docs, and it says this:

> You can't access the MongoDB from the outside of the server. To access
>   the MongoDB shell you need to log into your server by SSH first and
>   then run the following command.
>
> ```
> mongo appName
> ```

I tried that out and it works, but that's not good enough. I need to be able to access the database remotely. Is it simply impossible with a Meteor Up deployment?

One of the answers below seems to be suggesting that by setting the `MONGO_URL` in my `env` object, that I will basically be manually telling the database what url to respond to. Is that accurate?

### Update

The Meteor Up docs say the following:

> <appName> is the name of the database

So, on the advice of one of the answers, I edited my `mup.json` to include this:

```
// Configure environment
"env": {
  "ROOT_URL": "http://localhost/",
  "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://root:mypassword@127.0.0.1:27017/meteor"
  // My appName is "meteor", so that is the name of the database as well.
}
```

When I execute `mup deploy` with those variables, the deployment fails. Here's the first part of the error (if you'd like to see the rest let me know):

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/wait-for-mongo/bin/wait-for-mongo:14
    throw err;
```

When I use `mup reconfigure`, it doesn't fail, but then the website simply cannot be found at it's url. It seems to me that the `MONGO_URL` isn't a control mechanism, but merely a pointer to an outside database such as mongohq.

I'm thinking I'll have no choice but to resort to the `mongo appName` convention and an ssh python library, but **I'd love to find a way to directly access my database remotely and still keep using Meteor Up.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is impossible to remotely access the database, *if* Meteor Up installed and set it up for you. From the Meteor Up docs:

> You can't access the MongoDB from the outside of the server. To access
>   the MongoDB shell you need to log into your server by SSH first and
>   then run the following command.
>
> ```
> mongo appName
> ```

It can however be accessed in other ways than that `mongo appName` interface, *if* those programs are running on the server.

Digital Ocean Ubuntu droplets come equipped with Python 2.7, so using [pymongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.7rc0/tutorial.html) is possible. This command will connect you:

```python
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
```

That will automatically connect at `mongodb://localhost:27017/`

`pymongo` isn't a default package, so install `pip`, and then use `pip` to install `pymongo`.

```
apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential
pip install pymongo
```

Comment: You show it for Python, but how can we connect to the MongoDB locally via Java?

Comment: If anyone comes accross this and is on DO and has already deployed. use

Comment: If anyone comes accross this and is on DO and has already deployed. cd into your project: where your project code is. Then 'show dbs' : shows your databases. 'use databseName' now you can 'show collections' now you can db.collectionName.find() and any mongodb functions.

Answer (score 4):

It's because you did not set the MONGO_URL in the "env" object.

```
// Configure environment
"env": {
    "PORT": 58090, # Your application port
    "ROOT_URL": "http://localhost/",
    "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://username:password@127.0.0.1:27017/myDatabase",
    "METEOR_ENV": "production"  # If you need to separate your local environment from production
},
```

Then, just run `mup deploy`.

Comment: Wait really? I actually have control over what the `MONGO_URL` should be? It seems to me that since Meteor Up installed the database for me, it would just choose a URL. I'm confused about the actual purpose of the `env` variable. Could you point me in the direction of more info?

Comment: And what exactly does `myDatabase` point to? Some sort of configuration file?

Comment: `MyDatabase` is name of your database. You need to specify a `MONGO_URL` to allow your meteor application to connect to Mongo. [Check Step 9 of this tutorial](http://www.andrehonsberg.com/article/deploy-meteorjs-vhosts-ubuntu1204-mongodb-apache-proxy), it should help you to understand (it is not using Meteor Up though).

Comment: Check my edit. Meteor Up docs say that the database name is the same as the `appName`. I made that adjustment but it had the exact same result. I'm thinking I'll just have to resort to some sort of ssh tool. Meteor Up docs even say this: "MongoDB installed and bind to the local interface (cannot access from the outside)". That article you sent me (although containing extremely valuable information!) just doesn't apply in this case.

Answer (score 2):

It took me a while to figure this out. It is not possible to access the mongodb server from outside your hosting server. Therefore, you have to `ssh` into your server first and work from there. To connect to your db with pymongo, use the following:

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost/APPNAME')
posts = client.APPNAME.posts
```

APPNAME should be specified in your `mup.json` file and replace `posts` with whatever collection you must update.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a solution for accessing the DB with mupx on a digitalocean ubuntu 14.04 server.

After deployment of your app with mupx, do the following:

Login with ssh into your server, then install mongo: `apt-get install mongodb`

Then run the `mongo` command on your server. Try checking if your DB exists by running `show dbs`. If it is, then `use yourdbname`. It should hold all the data from your running app!

Let me know if it works. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I had this some problem but was able to use 3T MongoChef to do it. There is an option in MongoChef to connect to a DB via SSH and it worked like a charm. Hope this helps others out.

Here is the relevant screen in MongoChef from where you can do this.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the mongod.conf, to allow access from outside (a bit dangerous of course ;)

```
nano /etc/mongod.conf

# Listen to local interface only. Comment out to listen on all     interfaces.
# bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

then restart the server

```
service mongod stop
service mongod start
```

and you can access it from outside (using ssh-forwarding in robo-mongo)

Answer (score 0):

All I did was add the IP of my Digital ocean droplet server, instead of localhost, and it worked:

```
env: {
      ROOT_URL: 'http://yourdomain.com',
      MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://104.236.24.66:27017/meteor',
      PORT: 3002,
    },
```

Using this mongo instance in docker for 2 meteor apps currently.

EDIT: This depends on how your firewall is setup. Check with "ufw status". Also depends on how your mongo is deployed (which ports forwarded to where; ex) 0.0.0.0:27017->27017 ).