# Using Meteor App on iPad that was deployed to remote server with Meteor-up (issue connecting to mongodb)

Tags: mongodb, cordova, ipad, meteor, meteor-up

I've deployed a Meteor app to my own server with [Meteor-up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) which has worked out just fine if I try to connect to it through my browser. Now, I'm trying to connect to the app via my iPad.

I've built said app with the command **sudo meteor run ios-device** and envoked the MONGO_URL in the Meteor.startup function:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
        process.env.MONGO_URL = "mongodb://user:password@ipaddress:port/meteor";
    });
```

The issue is that I'm unable to connect to the mongo database that was created by Meteor-up. After [doing some digging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23786647/meteor-up-deployment-cant-use-meteor-mongo-url/23787804#23787804), I realized that Meteor-up specifically says you cannot access the MongoDB from outside the server.

> You can't access the MongoDB from the outside the server. To access
>   the MongoDB shell you need to log into your server via SSH first and
>   then run the following command:
>
> mongo appName

Instead, I attempted to load a mongo database that I had created locally onto my server, but still am unable to reach it on the iPad. I found a [potential work-around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23786647/meteor-up-deployment-cant-use-meteor-mongo-url/23787804#23787804) for this issue that uses pymongo but am wondering what other solutions are out there when using Meteor-Up. Or perhaps there may be a better meteor deployment option when dealing with mobile devices as well?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the app on your ipad, you shouldn't need to connect to the Mongo DB, but to the Meteor service.

This is probably just : ipaddress:port

Meteor's Explanation is here :
https://www.meteor.com/try/7

If you use this command :

`meteor run ios-device --mobile-server ipaddress:port`

Then you should just need to keep the Meteor (server) running on your server (from a separate window).

Comment: I partially resolved the issue I was having. It turns out I was missing environment variables that aren't documented by Meteor. Full details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948742/how-to-prevent-load-of-meteor-local-when-building-ios-app-with-phonegap